# Do I need to narrow my question further?

Tags: support, scope

I got great feedback on my question [If the USA disbanded, who would California rely on?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/239964/if-the-usa-disbanded-who-would-california-rely-on)

Originally I asked "If the USA disbanded, what alliances would form?" and it was pointed out to me that this was a "high concept" question that was too open-ended. There are many potential, conflicting answers. Could be fun, but not suitable for Stack Exchange. The question was closed.

So I narrowed the focus to "What is the smallest set of states that California could rely on for material needs?" My hope was that this is very concrete and therefore answerable. For example, someone had already shared a link to water sources for California.

I submitted to re-open but was declined. Is the answer still too broad? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm digging it!  Added my vote to reopen.

Comment: This is also why I think VTC should be thought of as "the nuclear option" rather than everyone's favorite first button. Give some feedback and a chance to clarify the question. If it's not fixed 24 hours later, then VTC. It's a lot harder to get eyes onto a topic to re-open after the button mashers have closed it, and I suspect it mostly discourages people from trying -- why spend your time fixing your question when you have no guarantee it will do any good?

Comment: And... reopened. Since Willk is one of the reopener, I bet they have some magic in their hat. They always have.

Comment: @Tortliena - any similarities between me and Frosty the Snowman end at the general body shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was one of the close-voter, I kinda owe you an answer :).

### No, I think you're good enough

While you could narrow it further (like focusing on food dependencies), it could be detrimental to your needs. Indeed, at some point you need to take a look at a bigger picture to work properly ^^.

So, right now this can be answered because answers will be implicitly scaled with the importance of the need (not very opinion-based). Food, water and electricity will come first, then secondary services and material.

Also, these needs should be accurately measurable for this <s>state</s> new country and is localized enough (specific enough). I mean California is big, but it's not as huge as the whole U.S.A.^^.

Finally, the question is clear and doesn't seem to be lacking critical data. And with the division of the U.S. there's a clear worldbuilding purpose.

Comment: thanks! I will see if I can clarify what I mean by "essential" - food, water and electricity should cover it, I think -- in the context of this question I would be concerned that, not being a state governor, I would forget something that is indeed "essential"

Comment: @LeeMcGee You can clearly state that "answers will be scaled according to how they are essentials to maintain today's lives", but you don't need to say that. It is already clear you want the big stuff, not the small worries like the absence of kitty cat food at the drugstore :).